# PySpark time out exception

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am running pySpark on Google Dataproc, and I am trying to work at scale with network graphs.

This is my configuration

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar'),
                                   ('spark.jars.packages', 'graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11')])

spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName('testing bq')\
  .config(conf=conf) \
  .getOrCreate()
```

However, when I run "label propagation" algorithm from graphframes on my network graph, it always returns *Py4JJavaError* due to some time out

```
result = g_df.labelPropagation(maxIter=5)
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o287.run.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 197.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 197.0 (TID 7247, cluster-network-graph-w-7.c.geotab-bi.internal, executor 50): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 50 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 127971 ms
```

How do I change this time out parameter from PySpark? What will it affect?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to `spark.network.timeout` which is 120s by default.

> Default timeout for all network interactions. This config will be used in place of spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout, spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs, spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout, spark.rpc.askTimeout or spark.rpc.lookupTimeout if they are not configured.

See [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).